# How to add a hyperlink to a XWPFRun

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

I want to format the text of a XWPF Run as a hyperlink. I am able to add it to the paragraph with the code given below but the adds it in a separate line.

```
 public static void appendExternalHyperlink(String url, String text, XWPFParagraph paragraph){

    //Add the link as External relationship
    String id=paragraph.getDocument().getPackagePart().addExternalRelationship(url, XWPFRelation.HYPERLINK.getRelation()).getId();

    //Append the link and bind it to the relationship
    CTHyperlink cLink=paragraph.getCTP().addNewHyperlink();
    cLink.setId(id);

    //Create the linked text
    CTText ctText=CTText.Factory.newInstance();
    ctText.setStringValue(text);
    CTR ctr=CTR.Factory.newInstance();
    ctr.setTArray(new CTText[]{ctText});
    CTRPr rpr = ctr.addNewRPr(); 
    CTColor colour = CTColor.Factory.newInstance(); 
    colour.setVal("0000FF"); rpr.setColor(colour); 
    CTRPr rpr1 = ctr.addNewRPr(); rpr1.addNewU().setVal(STUnderline.SINGLE);

    //Insert the linked text into the link
    cLink.setRArray(new CTR[]{ctr});
}
```

And I invoke it like:

```
XWPFParagraph eduPara = doc.createParagraph();
eduPara.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
eduPara.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.TOP);

XWPFRun eduRun7 = eduPara.createRun();
appendExternalHyperlink(center.getEduImpFile(), center.getEduImpFile(), eduPara);
eduRun7.addBreak();
```

Here **center** is an object that holds the values I need to print.The get functions give output in **String** format.

The output I get is as follows:

[Program Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZNoX.png)

I want the hyperlink to be in the same line as the previous run generating the text **"File uploaded:"**

Answer (score 0):

This was a mistake on my part as it was going to the next-line because there was not enough space to place the line.